# Auction Schema mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I need a sample schema for auction, it is about auction product, like: tophatter.com.
I created the schema but it is not complete. so there is my schema. only the models are here.

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose'
import autoIncrement from 'mongoose-auto-increment'
import { IAuction } from './../interfaces/IAuction'

const Auction = new Schema(
  {
    vendor: { type: Number, ref: 'User' },
    product: { type: Number, ref: 'Product' },
    price: Number,
    reserve: Number,
    status: Boolean,
    startTime: Date,
    endTime: Date,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
) 

Auction.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'Auction', startAt: 1 })

export default mongoose.model<IAuction & Document>('Auction', Auction)
```

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose'
import autoIncrement from 'mongoose-auto-increment'
import { IBidder } from './../interfaces/IBidder'

const Bidder = new Schema(
  {
    owner: { type: Number, ref: 'User' },
    auction: {
      type: Number,
      ref: 'Auction'
    },
    price: Number,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
) 

Bidder.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'Bidder', startAt: 1 })

export default mongoose.model<IBidder & Document>('Bidder', Bidder)
```